# Как моргать светодиодами без delay()?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Есть 4 светодиода. Мне надо чтобы 1 светодиод горел 8 секунд, а остальные 3 по 500 миллисекунд. Как это сделать? Код:

```
byte r1 = 2;
byte y1 = 3;
byte b1 = 4;
byte r2 = 5;
void setup() {
  pinMode(r1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(y1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(r2, OUTPUT);
}
void Svet1()
{
  digitalWrite(r2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(r1, HIGH);
}
void Svet2()
{
  digitalWrite(r1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(y1, HIGH);
}
void Svet3()
{
  digitalWrite(y1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b1, HIGH);
}
void Svet4()
{
  digitalWrite(b1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(r2, HIGH);
}
void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Позволю себе предположить, что программа будет работать на каком-то микроконтроллере. Тогда там должны быть аппаратные таймеры-счетчики. Нужно выбрать один из них, настроить на 500мс, и в обработчике прерывания от таймера менять состояние трех светодиодов при каждом вызове, а одного -каждый шестнадцатый вызов.

Comment: микроконтроллер Arduino

Comment: Я хотел сделать вот так. Только там промежутки мигания не могу настроить `uint8_t cycle = (millis() / 1000) % 11;
  if (cycle < 5) {
    Svet1();
  }
  else if (cycle < 7) {
    Svet2();
  }
  else if (cycle < 9) {
    Svet3();
  }
  else {
    Svet4();
  }`

Comment: Видимо, из вопроса я не очень понял, что и как должно срабатывать. Мне показалось, что они все одновременно должны моргать, но с разной частотой. Поясните, пожалуйста, более подробно: как должны работать светодиоды?

Comment: Сначала 8 секунд горит 1 светодиод(r1) и потом тухнет и горит уже 2 светодиод (y1), но горит он только пол секунды и тухнет, потом третий тоже горит пол секунды и тоже тухнет , 4 так же горит пол секунды и тухнет. Теперь все начинается сначала 1 светодиод(r1) опять горит 8 секунд и тухнет. потом следующие поочередно пол секунды горят и тухнут . Надеюсь, все понятно объяснил)

Comment: @ils2 А чем Вам delay не нравится. У Вас последовательные действия, никакой параллельности. Я так бы и делал, прямо в setup. Последовательно включал-выключал бы нужные диоды и использовал правильные задержки.

Comment: Проблема в том,что этот код я привел для примера. В настоящем коде много методов и функций и ардуино выполняет другой код. Там тоже надо как у светодиодов отдельно вызывать методы. Если использовать delay все зависает

Comment: Нет, delay, конечно, не надо, оно - зло :) Я бы сделал так: создал структуру с двумя полями. Первое: описание состояния светодиодов (горит/не горит) второе: длительность работы этого состояния. Объединил все состояния в массив. В обработчике таймера сделал счетчик, который сравнивал с длительностью текущего состояния. Если меньше - выходим из обработчика, увеличив счетчик. Если равно (или больше) - счетчик в ноль, переходим к следующему состоянию, зажигаем светодиоды так, как записано в структуре. Ну, и, конечно, нужна переменная статик с номером текущего состояния.

Comment: Можно код,пожалуйста)

Comment: @ils2 под  Arduino полным полно видео на youtube. Сам стал спецом за 4 часа. Почти всевозможные задачи разжеваны!

Comment: Ну окей. Спасибо

Comment: @ils2 Я не знаком с Arduino, так что код весьма примерный будет.

Comment: Для вашей задачи мог бы подойти PWM, не знаю есть ли он на ардуино. Гипотетически можно попробовать имулировать его на SPI.

Comment: Есть готовая библиотека для этого. Называется LEDseq.

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже сделал, как хотел.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда-то давно вендингом занимался, тоже надо было написать легковестную библиотеку которая бы не блокировала основной поток Delay'ями

https://github.com/latdev/eugenetaskstool

Вот пример использования

```
#include <ectask.h>

TasksTool timelib;

void Once30sec() {
  Serial.println("This will run once 30 seconds from Arduino starts");
  timelib.once(1000, ThisWillRunOnceAfter30SecondOnce);
}

void Every15sec() {
  Serial.println("This will runs every 15 seconds");
}

void Every40sec() {
  Serial.println("This will runs every 40 seconds");
  timelib.once(1000, ThisWillRunNotOnceAfter40SecondOnce);
}

void ThisWillRunNotOnceAfter40SecondOnce() {
  Serial.println("One second after 40 passed");
}

void ThisWillRunOnceAfter30SecondOnce() {
  Serial.println("One second after 30 passed");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  timelib.once(30000, Once30sec);
  timelib.every(15000, Every15sec);
  timelib.every(40000, Every40sec);
}

void loop() {
  timelib.loop(); // This is important part of timers
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот часть библиотеки, использующей сторожевой таймер для этой цели

```
#include <avr/io.h> 
#include <avr/interrupt.h>



volatile unsigned long int cikle;


    class Interval{
        unsigned long int temp;
        bool f1;
        public:
        bool interval(unsigned int time,  void (*func)(),bool f=1); //выполнение функции через определённые интервалы времени (мс). должна находиться в цикле
    };

    void delay(unsigned long int time);     //создание задержки (мс)
    void wBegin();                          //инициализация сторожевого таймера
    unsigned long int getCicle();           //возвращает время(кратное 16) в миллисекундах с начала запуска программы 


//################################################

    ISR(WDT_vect)
        {
        cikle+=16;
        }

        unsigned long int getCicle(){
        return cikle;} 

    void wBegin(){

                WDTCSR |= 1 << WDCE;
                WDTCSR |= 0b01000000; // 1 переполнение -- 16 мс
        sei();
        }

    void delay(unsigned long int time){
        unsigned long int t=getCicle();
        while(getCicle()-t<(time));
        return;
        }


bool Interval::interval(unsigned int time, void (*func)(),bool f) {
    if (f) {
        if(f1){
            f1 = 0;
            temp = getCicle();
            func();
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            if (getCicle() - temp >= time)f1 = 1;
            return 0;
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Если вставить её в начало или вынести в отдельную библиотеку , то дальше можно сделать так

```
//тут вставить верхний код
    byte r1 = 2;
    byte y1 = 3;
    byte b1 = 4;
    byte r2 = 5;

    boolean L1 = 0;
    boolean L2 = 0;
    boolean L3 = 0;
    boolean L4 = 0;

    void Svet1();
    void Svet2();
    void Svet3();
    void Svet4();

Interval Led1, Led2, Led3, Led4;

    void setup() {

      pinMode(r1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(y1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(b1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(r2, OUTPUT);
      wBegin();
    }

    void loop() {
    Led1.interval(8000,Svet1,1);
    Led1.interval(500,Svet2,1);
    Led1.interval(500,Svet3,1);
    Led1.interval(500,Svet4,1);
    }

void Svet1()
    {
      if(L1)  digitalWrite(r1, HIGH);
      else    digitalWrite(r1, LOW);
    }
    void Svet2()
    {
      if(L2)  digitalWrite(r2, HIGH);
      else    digitalWrite(r2, LOW);
    }
    void Svet3()
    {
      if(L3)  digitalWrite(r3, HIGH);
      else    digitalWrite(r3, LOW);
    }
    void Svet4()
    {
      if(L4)  digitalWrite(r4, HIGH);
      else    digitalWrite(r4, LOW);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так: создал структуру с двумя полями. Первое: описание состояния светодиодов (горит/не горит) второе: длительность работы этого состояния. Объединил все состояния в массив. В обработчике таймера сделал счетчик, который сравнивал с длительностью текущего состояния. Если меньше - выходим из обработчика, увеличив счетчик. Если равно (или больше) - счетчик в ноль, переходим к следующему состоянию, зажигаем светодиоды так, как записано в структуре. Ну, и, конечно, нужна переменная статик с номером текущего состояния. Вот набросок кода:

```
struct SD {         // Структура, описывающая состояние светодоидов.
    bool sd1;
    bool sd2;
    bool sd3;
    bool sd4
}

struct States {     // Состояние сисетмы и длительность состояния.
    SD state;
    int time;
}

State[5] stm;       // Набор сосятояний.


interrupt Timer1 {
static int curr_state = 0;      // Текущее состояние
static unsigned int count;      // время с начала состояния

    if (count >= stm[curr_state]) {
        curr_state = (curr_state >=4) ? 0 : (++curr_state);
        count = 0;
        // Здесь выполняем установку нового состояния диодов
    }
    else ++count;
}
```

Comment: Статические переменные для состояния и цикл для замера времени - не самые лучшие идеи

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Не знаю, чем Вам не нравятся статические переменные, но о цикле я точно ничего не говорил.

Comment: чем не нравятся статические переменные? Вы наверно сейчас пошутили - если нет, то возьмите любую книгу по c++ (Прата, Страуструп, можно даже Кернела и Ритчи по Си) и почитайте. По поводу цикла - да, действительно, в свое оправдание скажу: нужно форматировать свой код.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, код отформатирован, вообще-то. И перед кодом честно сказано, что это лишь набросок. И я все же хочу попросить Вас по-подробнее высказаться о статических переменных. И что Вы предлагаете использовать вместо них.

Comment: повторюсь: об этом писали уже миллионы раз люди, которые сами создавали языки программирования и компиляторы к ним. Что касается альтернативы, в случае если без статики не обойтись (это не тот случай), то используется синглтон.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Наверное, можно обойтись без статики (хотя с разбегу ,я не вижу как), но что касается синглтона... О нем тоже много интересного написано, и я не уверен, что для предложенной задачи он будет лучше, чем статика. Но Вашу мысль я понял, на этом предлагаю закончить обсуждение, дабы не засорять комментарии.

Comment: Статические переменные в embedded системах вполне себе комильфо (из за ограниченности ресурсов).